# PySide2/QML Filtering hierarchical data at given root index

Tags: python, qml, pyside2, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm trying to filter QStandardItemModel (with hierarchical data) using QSortFilterProxyModel (with setRecursiveFilteringEnabled to True) which update on QML TextField:onTextChanged event.

The resultant proxy model seems empty and returns warnings like 
`QSortFilterProxyModel: index from wrong model passed to mapToSource`

So please tell me what's wrong in my code ? How can i start filtering from source model current rootIndex ?

**crumbsProxy.py**

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtQuick, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQml
import sys

crumbs_data = {"books":{
    "web":{
      "front-end":{
        "html":["the missing manual", "core html5 canvas"],
        "css":["css pocket reference", "css in depth"],
        "js":["you don't know js", "eloquent javascript"]
      },
      "back-end":{
        "php":["modern php", "php web services"],
        "python":["dive into python", "python for everybody", 
        "Think Python", "Effective Python", "Fluent Python"]
      }
    },
    "database":{
      "sql":{
        "mysql":["mysql in a nutshell", "mysql cookbook"],
        "postgresql":["postgresql up and running", "practical postgresql"]
      },
      "nosql":{
        "mongodb":["mongodb in action", "scaling mongodb"],
        "cassandra":["practical cassandra", "mastering cassandra"]
}}}}


def dict_to_model(item, d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(k)
            item.appendRow(it)
            dict_to_model(it, v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            dict_to_model(item, v)
    else:
        item.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(d)))

class crumbsProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(crumbsProxyModel,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(True)

    def mapFromSource(self, index):
        return self.createIndex(index.column(), index.row())      


class NavigationManager(QtCore.QObject):
    headersChanged = QtCore.Signal()
    rootIndexChanged = QtCore.Signal("QModelIndex")

    def __init__(self, json_data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        dict_to_model(self.m_model.invisibleRootItem(), json_data)

        self.m_headers = []
        self.m_rootindex = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        self.rootIndexChanged.connect(self._update_headers)

        self.rootIndex = self.m_model.index(0, 0)

        self.proxy_model = crumbsProxyModel()
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.m_model)

    def _update_headers(self, ix):
        self.m_headers = []
        while ix.isValid():
            self.m_headers.insert(0, [ix, ix.data()])
            ix = ix.parent()
        self.headersChanged.emit()

    @QtCore.Property(QtCore.QObject, constant=True)
    def model(self):
        #return self.m_model
        return self.proxy_model

    @QtCore.Property("QVariantList", notify=headersChanged)
    def headers(self):
        return self.m_headers

    def get_root_index(self):
        return self.m_rootindex

    def set_root_index(self, ix):
        if self.m_rootindex != ix:
            self.m_rootindex = ix
            self.rootIndexChanged.emit(ix)

    rootIndex = QtCore.Property("QModelIndex", fget=get_root_index, fset=set_root_index, notify=rootIndexChanged)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    navigation_manager = NavigationManager(crumbs_data)
    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("navigation_manager", navigation_manager)
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "CrumbsMain.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**CrumbsMain.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13
import QtQml.Models 2.13

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindowId
    visible: true
    width: 960
    height: 540
    title: qsTr("Breadcrumbs Test")

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        ColumnLayout {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            spacing: 6

            TextField {
                id: filterTextFieldId
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 40
                font {
                    family: "SF Pro Display"
                 pixelSize: 22
                }
                placeholderText: "Type Filter Expression"
                color: "dodgerblue"
                onTextChanged: 
                    {
                        if (text != '')
                        navigation_manager.model.setFilterRegExp(text)
                    }
            }

            ToolBar {
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "transparent"
                }
                RowLayout {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    spacing: 10
                    Repeater{
                        model: navigation_manager.headers
                        ToolButton {
                            Layout.preferredHeight: 20
                            contentItem: Text {
                                text: model.modelData[1]
                                color: "#FFFFFF"
                                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            }
                            background: Rectangle {
                                radius: 12
                                color:  "#40e0d0"
                            }
                            onClicked: navigation_manager.rootIndex = model.modelData[0]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "dodgerblue"

                ListView{
                    id: view
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 12
                    model: DelegateModel {
                        model: navigation_manager.model
                        rootIndex: navigation_manager.rootIndex
                        delegate: Rectangle {
                            height: 25
                            color:"transparent"
                            Text { 
                                text: model.display
                                color:"white"
                                MouseArea{
                                    anchors.fill: parent
                                    onClicked: {
                                        if (model.hasModelChildren)
                                            {navigation_manager.rootIndex = view.model.modelIndex(index)}
                                        else
                                            {console.log(navigation_manager.headers)}
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors:

- It is not necessary to implement mapFromSource.
- The m_rootindex must be part of the model that you export to the QML, that is, the proxy, but in your case you do not.

Considering the above, the solution is:

```py
class CrumbsProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setRecursiveFilteringEnabled(True)


class NavigationManager(QtCore.QObject):
    headersChanged = QtCore.Signal()
    rootIndexChanged = QtCore.Signal("QModelIndex")

    def __init__(self, json_data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        dict_to_model(self.m_model.invisibleRootItem(), json_data)

        self.m_headers = []
        self.m_rootindex = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        self.rootIndexChanged.connect(self._update_headers)

        self.proxy_model = CrumbsProxyModel()
        self.proxy_model.setSourceModel(self.m_model)
        self.m_rootindex = self.proxy_model.mapFromSource(self.m_model.index(0, 0))

    def _update_headers(self, ix)
        # ...
```

---

#### Update:

When activating the recursiveFilteringEnabled property of QSortFilterProxyModel you only indicate that you want to filter on all the items of the model, and if an item match then your parents will be visible, but that does not fit with what you require: only filter the items that are children of rootIndex.

Considering this a possible solution could implement a custom filter using QSortFilterProxyModel but that can be tedious and inefficient. Another alternative is to filter using the DelegateModel through "group".

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
├── CrumbsMain.qml
├── crumbsProxy.py
└── FilterModel.qml
```

**crumbsProxy.py**

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtQuick, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQml
import sys

crumbs_data = {
    "books": {
        "web": {
            "front-end": {
                "html": ["the missing manual", "core html5 canvas"],
                "css": ["css pocket reference", "css in depth"],
                "js": ["you don't know js", "eloquent javascript"],
            },
            "back-end": {
                "php": ["modern php", "php web services"],
                "python": [
                    "dive into python",
                    "python for everybody",
                    "Think Python",
                    "Effective Python",
                    "Fluent Python",
                ],
            },
        },
        "database": {
            "sql": {
                "mysql": ["mysql in a nutshell", "mysql cookbook"],
                "postgresql": ["postgresql up and running", "practical postgresql"],
            },
            "nosql": {
                "mongodb": ["mongodb in action", "scaling mongodb"],
                "cassandra": ["practical cassandra", "mastering cassandra"],
            },
        },
    }
}


def dict_to_model(item, d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            it = QtGui.QStandardItem(k)
            item.appendRow(it)
            dict_to_model(it, v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            dict_to_model(item, v)
    else:
        item.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(str(d)))


class NavigationManager(QtCore.QObject):
    headersChanged = QtCore.Signal()
    rootIndexChanged = QtCore.Signal("QModelIndex")

    def __init__(self, json_data, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.m_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
        dict_to_model(self.m_model.invisibleRootItem(), json_data)

        self.m_headers = []
        self.m_rootindex = QtCore.QModelIndex()
        self.rootIndexChanged.connect(self._update_headers)

        self.rootIndex = self.m_model.index(0, 0)

    def _update_headers(self, ix):
        self.m_headers = []
        while ix.isValid():
            self.m_headers.insert(0, [ix, ix.data()])
            ix = ix.parent()
        self.headersChanged.emit()

    @QtCore.Property(QtCore.QObject, constant=True)
    def model(self):
        return self.m_model

    @QtCore.Property("QVariantList", notify=headersChanged)
    def headers(self):
        return self.m_headers

    def get_root_index(self):
        return self.m_rootindex

    def set_root_index(self, ix):
        if self.m_rootindex != ix:
            self.m_rootindex = ix
            self.rootIndexChanged.emit(ix)

    rootIndex = QtCore.Property(
        "QModelIndex", fget=get_root_index, fset=set_root_index, notify=rootIndexChanged
    )

    @QtCore.Slot(str, str, result=bool)
    def filter(self, word, wilcard):
        rx = QtCore.QRegExp(wilcard)
        rx.setPatternSyntax(QtCore.QRegExp.Wildcard)
        return rx.indexIn(word) != -1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    navigation_manager = NavigationManager(crumbs_data)

    model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("navigation_manager", navigation_manager)
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "CrumbsMain.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**CrumbsMain.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.13
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.13
import QtQml.Models 2.13

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindowId
    visible: true
    width: 960
    height: 540
    title: qsTr("Breadcrumbs Test")

    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        ColumnLayout {
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            spacing: 6

            TextField {
                id: filterTextFieldId
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.preferredHeight: 40
                font {
                    family: "SF Pro Display"
                 pixelSize: 22
                }
                placeholderText: "Type Filter Expression"
                color: "dodgerblue"
                onTextChanged: filtermodel.update()
            }

            ToolBar {
                background: Rectangle {
                    color: "transparent"
                }
                RowLayout {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    spacing: 10
                    Repeater{
                        model: navigation_manager.headers
                        ToolButton {
                            Layout.preferredHeight: 20
                            contentItem: Text {
                                text: model.modelData[1]
                                color: "#FFFFFF"
                                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            }
                            background: Rectangle {
                                radius: 12
                                color:  "#40e0d0"
                            }
                            onClicked: navigation_manager.rootIndex = model.modelData[0]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                color: "dodgerblue"

                ListView{
                    id: view
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 12
                    model: FilterModel {
                        id: filtermodel
                        filter: function(item) {
                            return navigation_manager.filter(item.display, filterTextFieldId.text)
                        }
                        model: navigation_manager.model
                        rootIndex: navigation_manager.rootIndex
                        delegate: Rectangle {
                            height: 25
                            color:"transparent"
                            Text { 
                                text: model.display
                                color:"white"
                                MouseArea{
                                    anchors.fill: parent
                                    onClicked: {
                                        if (model.hasModelChildren){
                                            navigation_manager.rootIndex = view.model.modelIndex(index)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FilterModel.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQml.Models 2.13

DelegateModel{
    property var filter: function(item) { return true; }
    function update() {
        if (items.count > 0) {
            items.setGroups(0, items.count, "items");
        }
        var visible = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.count; ++i) {
            var item = items.get(i);
            if (filter(item.model)) {
                visible.push(item);
            }
        }
        for(var i in visible){
            item = visible[i];
            item.inVisible = true;
        }
    }
    items.onChanged: update()
    onFilterChanged: update()
    groups: DelegateModelGroup {
        id: visibleItems
        name: "visible"
        includeByDefault: false
    }
    filterOnGroup: "visible"
}
```

Comment: everything works fine, only issue is, if item doesn't have child then it returns first root index of model

Comment: @Ruchit explain yourself better, my objective in this question is only to indicate where the error is, maybe you have a bad knowledge of the objective of QSortFilterProxyModel and setRecursiveFilteringEnabled so before that I need more detail: 1) show what you get (one image would be enough) 2) show what What do you want to get (one image would be enough).

Comment: @Ruchit Okay, I understood you. It seems you don't understand how a proxy works. In a few moments I will update my answer.

Comment: Ok thanks and you're right , I'm newbie on Model-View.

Comment: @Ruchit Is it necessary for the filter to be made by a regex?

Comment: i want to perform wildcard search..for ex...Item*, item_1*, item_####, etc.

Comment: Ok, now it's working fine. Plus group based filter seems quite faster. Thanks